# Color key for d3heatmap in R?

Tags: r

is there any way to specify color key for d3heatmap in R? following is the code with which I am able to make the heatmap but could not show a color key. Kindly provide some answers.

```
library(d3heatmap)
d3heatmap(data, Rowv = TRUE, Colv = TRUE,
distfun = dist, hclustfun = hclust, dendrogram = c("both", "row",
"column", "none"), reorderfun = function(d, w) reorder(d, w), k_row=400, symm = FALSE, scale = "row", na.rm = TRUE,labRow = rownames(data), labCol = colnames(data), digits = 3L,theme = NULL, color = scales::col_quantile("Blues", NULL, 5),
width = 960, height = 500, xaxis_height = 80, yaxis_width = 120,
xaxis_font_size = "12pt", yaxis_font_size = "12pt", brush_color ="#0000FF",
show_grid = TRUE, anim_duration = 0)
```

Comment: This MWE produces an error: `Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'`.  Perhaps specify your `sessionInfo()` for more information.